# Message when a WebView's window is closed?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

In my program I have an NSPanel containing a web view appear to a user to have them authenticate on a web page.  I want to monitor if the user is closing the WebView before the authentication is complete.

I looked for messages in the WebFrameLoadDelegate protocol but I couldn't seem to find any message that would fire when the user clicks the close button for the NSPanel and only when the user clicks the close button.

I looked at subclassing NSWindowController and overriding the close method.  Perhaps I did it wrong, because even when I removed the [super close] call, the panel still closed.

So, what is the correct procedure for executing extra code when the NSPanel containing the WebView closes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to stop the user from closing a window, you need to [set the window's style mask](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWindow/setStyleMask%3a) to one that doesn't include [NSCloseableWindowMask](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSClosableWindowMask). This will disable the window's close button, so that it can only be closed programmatically. In the simplest case, you can just do `[panel setStyleMask:[panel styleMask] ^ NSCloseableWindowMask]`.

Also, if you want to override a window's closing behavior, you either need to override NSWindow's (not NSWindowController's) `close` method, or implement `windowShouldClose:` on the window's delegate. I think the second way is better. At any rate, `-[NSWindowController close]` is just a convenience method to close the window. It isn't what's normally invoked when a window closes.